# How to get the audio current time and show message using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, audio

I need help. I want to get the html5 audio current time and display a message with the specified time.

I pulled some codes from the internet. Please see the code below.

**HTML**

```
<audio id="track" controls><source src="[sourceToAudioFile]" type="audio/mpeg"></audio> 
<input type="text" id="currentTime">
<div id="message"></div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            var audio = document.getElementById('track');
            audio.addEventListener('timeupdate', function () {
                var currentTimeS = audio.currentTime;
                //console.log(currentTimeMs);

                $('#currentTime').val(currentTimeS);

                var current = $('#currentTime').val();
                var timeset = 1.694568; //this might be changed

                $('#timeset').text(current);

                if (current === timeset) {
                    $("#message").text('Equal time!');
                }

            }, false);

        });

    </script>
```

My problem is I cannot able to display the message with the specified time.

Here is my working example. Please check.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/johnlopev/evu9fgtb/8/)

Any idea what is wrong with this code? I really appreciate your help out there. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: what issue did you face with this code?

Comment: @Rohit416 I cannot display the message with the specified time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made some changes in `JavaScript` section of the code..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var audio = document.getElementById('track');
        audio.addEventListener('timeupdate', function () {
            var timeSet = 1.694568;
            var _currentTime = parseFloat(audio.currentTime);                

            $('#currentTime').val(_currentTime);
            $('#timeset').text(_currentTime);

            if (_currentTime === timeSet) {
                $("#message").text('Equal time!');
            }

        }, false);

    });
</script>
```

Let me know if it works for you. Besides it is not necessary to use `parseFloat()` here because you have set the value in `timeSet` which is already in proper fractional format. I added it for making sure comparison works always because of `===` operator which will not do type conversion. It would be more handy if the fractional value was written as a string i.e. `"1.694568"`.

#### Update:

For checking the value like exact `10` seconds, you can compare the result with `currentTime` using [`Math.round()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round) which is rather easy than comparing it with a fractional value like `1.694568` because of the interval step of `currentTime`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var audio = document.getElementById('track');
    audio.addEventListener('timeupdate', function () {
      var timeSet = 10;
      var _currentTime = Math.round(audio.currentTime);

      $('#currentTime').val(_currentTime);
      $('#timeset').text(_currentTime);

      if (_currentTime === timeSet) {
        $("#message").text('Equal time!');
      }
    }, false);
});
```

Here is the [**updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/evu9fgtb/41/).

Comment: I checked the console statements and it appears the `_currentTime` never get matched with the exact value of `timeSet` possibly due to the interval steps of the seeking bar.

Comment: Otherwise there is nothing wrong with the code but it needs little modification as the exact fractional value of `timeSet` has to be matched. Please look for the resources. Check the [console output in this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/evu9fgtb/12/).

Comment: So, how I can I make it equal value of the audio's current time? It seems that there is a decimal value of the current time if somebody can solve also on how to make it an exact number of seconds. I do appreciate with your help.

Comment: I want an exact number like 10 seconds. Actually it will be change depending whatI like to set.

Answer (score 1):

@Rohit416 Thank you so much for helping me get through with this.
I added `Math.round` so I can get the exact value of integer to display the message.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var audio = document.getElementById('track');
        audio.addEventListener('timeupdate', function () {
          var timeSet = 5;
          var _currentTime = Math.round(audio.currentTime);

          $('#currentTime').val(_currentTime);
          $('#timeset').text(_currentTime);

          if (_currentTime === timeSet) {
            $("#message").text('Equal time!');
          }else{
            $("#message").text('NO');
          }

        }, false);

    });
```

Here is the updated working example: [UPDATED Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/johnlopev/evu9fgtb/35/)